# OBIEE 12c How to skip filter page in prompt

Tags: oracle12c, obiee

I am trying to create a simple hierarchy in OBI, after adding prompts to the sub analysis. When ever I click on the main analysis, it always shows a filter first and I have to click the okay button to get to the next analysis. Is there any way to remove this? The value can be auto selected, I really don't want to click this okay button manually. Please see screenshots below, I want to remove the second step.

[image: Main analysis]

[image: Step I want to skip]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hide the dashboard prompt, so it gets applied with default values, or you don't even need a dashboard prompt in this example, using GoUrl functionality the value is passed.